# Elixir / Phoenix - Run code at the very beginning of a test run, shared data for ALL tests

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

I'd like to run a block of code right at the beginning of my test suite (that inserts data into the database!), and persists across the entirety of the test suite.

Is something like this possible?

I tried running the code in a `setup_all` block, but:
A) I was getting failures trying to insert into the database here;
B) This would only be shared between that test module, whereas I'd like it to be shared across all tests.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Put it into `test/test_helper.exs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Run once before starting tests

Just put the common code in your `test/test_helper.exs`:

```
ExUnit.start()

# Common Code
ModuleOne.some_method
ModuleTwo.other_method(args) # etc
```

---

### Run before every test

Assuming you have already worked out cleaning up the db and running migrations between tests, you can put something like this in your `test/test_helper.exs`:

```
defmodule TestProject.Helpers do
  def setup do
    # Common Code
  end
end
```

And use this `setup` block in all of your tests:

```
setup do
  TestProject.Helpers.setup
end
```

---

### Setting up a Test Database / Schema

If you also need to set up a fake Database, Schema and Migrations for your tests, you'll need to define them as well, and put this in your `test_helper` (assuming here that the driver you are using is `Postgrex`):

```
# Start Ecto
{:ok, _} = Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.ensure_all_started(TestProject.Repo, :temporary)
_        = Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.storage_down(TestProject.Repo.config)
:ok      = Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.storage_up(TestProject.Repo.config)
{:ok, _} = TestProject.Repo.start_link
```

[*For a more detailed example, you can see my `Ecto.Rut` package that creates a fake database (for the `test` env only), and resets it before running each test.*](https://github.com/sheharyarn/ecto_rut/blob/master/test/test_helper.exs)

Comment: I only just got notified about this answer. Thanks for your response. I did figure this out, but I'll accept your answer as it's pretty close to what I ended up with :)